# Conditional display of calculated fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

I'm working on a table named FCT_HISTO_PORTES that contains ID_MVT_EXPL and ID_PTE fields which are integers. In this table a ID_MVT_EXPL is associated with one, two or three ID_PTE.

Here's an example:

```
select top 1000
ID_MVT_EXPL,
ID_PTE
from FCT_HISTO_PORTES

ID_MVT_EXPL ID_PTE
3945546     6
3945547     25
3945548     56
3945548     57
3945549     25
3945550     52
3945551     57
3945551     58
3945553     56
3945557     51
3945558     57
3945558     58
```

You can see that "3945546" has one ID_PTE and "3945548" has two different ID_PTE.

The aim of the game is that I can display a single line for each ID_MVT_EXPL with named fields ID_PTE_1, ID_PTE_2, ID_PTE_3.

I tried with this SELECT but the result is incorrect because all the ID_PTE fit into ID_PTE_1 and leave the other two to NULL.

```
select top 1000
ID_MVT_EXPL,
MIN(id_pte) as ID_PTE_1,
case 
    when COUNT(id_pte) = 2
    then MAX(id_pte) 
    when COUNT(id_pte) = 3
    then SUM(id_pte)-(MIN(ID_PTE)+MAX(ID_PTE))
end as ID_PTE_2,
case 
    when COUNT(id_pte) = 3
    then MAX(id_pte)
end as ID_PTE_3
from FCT_HISTO_PORTES
group by ID_MVT_EXPL, ID_PTE

ID_MVT_EXPL ID_PTE_1 ID_PTE_2 ID_PTE_3
3945546     6        NULL     NULL
3945547     25       NULL     NULL
3945548     56       NULL     NULL
3945548     57       NULL     NULL
3945549     25       NULL     NULL
3945550     52       NULL     NULL
3945551     57       NULL     NULL
3945551     58       NULL     NULL
3945553     56       NULL     NULL
3945557     51       NULL     NULL
3945558     57       NULL     NULL
3945558     58       NULL     NULL
```

So what needs to change in my SELECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is a little bit different. But if I understand you correct. You could do this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID_MVT_EXPL INT, ID_PTE INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(3945546,6),(3945547,25),(3945548,56),(3945548,57),
(3945549,25),(3945550,52),(3945551,57),(3945551,58),
(3945553,56),(3945557,51),(3945558,57),(3945558,58)
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    pvt.ID_MVT_EXPL,
    pvt.[1] AS ID_PTE_1,
    pvt.[2] AS ID_PTE_2,
    pvt.[3] AS ID_PTE_3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID_MVT_EXPL ORDER BY ID_PTE) AS RowNbr,
        tbl.ID_MVT_EXPL,
        tbl.ID_PTE
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ID_PTE)
    FOR RowNbr IN([1],[2],[3])
) AS pvt
```

**Output:**

```
3945546 6   NULL    NULL
3945547 25  NULL    NULL
3945548 56  57      NULL
3945549 25  NULL    NULL
3945550 52  NULL    NULL
3945551 57  58      NULL
3945553 56  NULL    NULL
3945557 51  NULL    NULL
3945558 57  58      NULL
```

**Reference:**

- [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)
- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah your suggestion works so thank you very much ! :)